# Failed installation of Calipso under NodeJS

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

Which configuration file do I have to kill (or just modify) in order to get [Calipso](http://calip.so/) `npm install` to yield `ok`?

Here's the installation log:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@0.2.11-5
npm info using node@v0.4.9
npm info calculating sha1 /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/.cache/calipso/0.2.0/package.tgz
npm info shasum 8c894356ba35bcb7ec9a8dbd4abf545a65fe34fe
npm info range jade@>=0.11.0
npm info range stylus@>=0.12.2
npm info range express@>=2.2.1
npm info range mime@>=1.2.2
npm info range winston@>=0.2.7
npm info range request@>=1.9.5
npm info range connect-form@>=0.2.1
npm info range ejs@>=0.3.1
npm info range underscore@>=1.1.6
npm info range qs@>=0.1.0
npm info range mongodb@>=0.9.3
npm info range pool@>=0.4.1
npm info range connect@>=1.3.0
npm info range mongoose@>=1.2.0
npm info range cluster@>=0.6.0
npm info range eyes@0.1.x
npm info range pkginfo@0.2.x
npm info range loggly@0.3.x
npm info range log@>= 1.2.0
npm info range formidable@>= 0.9.3
```

From here on it breaks:

```
npm info fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/hooks/-/hooks-0.1.9.tgz
npm info calculating sha1 /var/folders/L5/L5b8zccxFYiv8aXPH4Xpr++++TI/-Tmp-/npm-1311158342434/1311158345082-0.03321287292055786/tmp.tgz
npm info shasum 064e8bba3fca0e6611408c011ba7958c1055bb4e
npm ERR! Error: Using '>=' with 0.4.x makes no sense. Don't do it.
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/npm/0.2.11-5/libexec/lib/utils/semver.js:94:29
npm ERR!     at String.replace (native)
npm ERR!     at replaceXRange (/usr/local/Cellar/npm/0.2.11-5/libexec/lib/utils/semver.js:88:25)
npm ERR!     at Array.map (native)
npm ERR!     at replaceXRanges (/usr/local/Cellar/npm/0.2.11-5/libexec/lib/utils/semver.js:84:17)
npm ERR!     at Array.map (native)
npm ERR!     at toComparators (/usr/local/Cellar/npm/0.2.11-5/libexec/lib/utils/semver.js:66:8)
npm ERR!     at Object.validRange (/usr/local/Cellar/npm/0.2.11-5/libexec/lib/utils/semver.js:138:11)
npm ERR!     at testEngine (/usr/local/Cellar/npm/0.2.11-5/libexec/lib/utils/read-json.js:218:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/npm/0.2.11-5/libexec/lib/utils/read-json.js:159:10
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at 
npm ERR! or email it to 
npm ERR! Just tweeting a tiny part of the error will not be helpful.
npm info range timespan@2.x.x
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hooks-js has a corrupted [package.json](https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js/blob/master/package.json) file.

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.4.x"
},
```

Basically hooks-js says it will work with any version of node >=0.4. This is silly, it's not completely future proof, it can't be.

The reason the installation worked at some point in the past is probably that this is a new piece of validation on npmjs.

An alternative fix would be to use an older version of npm or install hooks-js manually.

A better fix would be to complain to the author. Go leave [an issue](https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js/issues)

Comment: Thanks you. Posted an issue; hope it'll be fixed somewhen. Can you point me in the right direction for manually installing hooks-js?

Comment: @konzepz fork it, fix it. Dump the code in the .node_modules folder. All npm does is dumps a lot of code in the .node_modules folder, you can do that manually

Comment: Fixed; issue closed: https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js/issues/1#issuecomment-1617628